# Create new pandas dataframe column containing boolean output from searching for substrings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to create a new column where if a substring is found in an existing column, it will return True and vice versa.

So in this example, I'd like to search for the substring "abc" in column a and create a Boolean column b whether column a contained the string or not.

```
a      b
zabc   True
wxyz   False
abcy   True
defg   False
```

I've tried something like

```
df['b'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: True if 'abc' in x else False)
```

But this gave me an error saying "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

I also tried

```
df['b'] = False
df['b'][df['a'].str.contains('abc')] = True
```

But I got the error "cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values"

Can someone explain the errors and what I can do about it. I have confirmed that ['a'] exists and contains values. But there are rows that contain None values.

Comment: have you tried `df['a'].apply(lambda x: 'abc' in x)`? `apply` is what you want to use for a series.

Comment: or just `df['a'].str.contains('abc')`

Comment: You have `None` values in `df[a]`, which are causing the problem. The solutions suggested will work, but note that `df[b]` will be `None` when `df[a]` is `None`. If that's not something you like, you can first replace all the `None` values in `df[a]` with empty string.

Comment: `df['a'].apply(lambda x: 'abc' in x)` wont work, `df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('abc'), axis=1)` will if you want to use `apply`, but your answer is the "cleanest" method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best solution but you can check for null values with `pd.isnull()` or convert null values to a string with `str()`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['zabc', None, 'abcy', 'defg']})


df['a'].map(lambda x: True if 'abc' in str(x) else False)
```

or

```
df['a'].map(lambda x: False if pd.isnull(x) or 'abc' not in x else True)
```

Reuslt:

```
    0     True
    1    False
    2     True
    3    False
    Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 6):

This how to do it.

```py
df["b"] = df["a"].str.contains("abc")
```

Regarding your error.

It's seems that you have np.nan value in your column a, then the method str.contain will return np.nan for those value, as you try to index with an array containing np.nan value, pandas tell you that is not possible.

Comment: thanks! So in an earlier step, i had converted the empty strings to None for them to properly be treated as nulls. Is it better to keep them as empty strings? or converted those None back to empty strings just for that column?

Comment: @just4lizzy If you convert empty strings to null you want to use `np.nan` and not `None`.  `np.nan` allows for vectorized operations; its a float value, while `None`, by definition, forces object type, which basically disables all efficiency in numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is ok, here is the output on my sample.

```
s = pd.Series(['cat','hat','dog','fog','pet'])
d = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['test'])
d['b'] = d['test'].map(lambda x: True if 'og' in x else False)
d
```

[image]