# How to extract rows from a dataframe that contain only certain values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data set:

```
| Country |Languages Spoken |


|  Afghanistan  |   Dari Persian, Pashtu (both official), other Turkic and minor languages      
|  Algeria      | Arabic (official), French, Berber dialects                                    
|Andorra        | Catalán (official), French, Castilian, Portuguese                             
|Angola         | Portuguese (official), Bantu and other African languages                      
|Antigua and Barbuda |  English (official), local dialects 

|Australia      |          English 79%, native and other languages
```

and I want to extract all the english speeaking countries, I think the easiest way would be to extract all the countries that have the word 'English' in the languages, ideally i want to have a new dataframe with the column english speaking and with values true or false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new pandas dataframe column containing boolean output from searching for substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421837/create-new-pandas-dataframe-column-containing-boolean-output-from-searching-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One implementation of what you describe using [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```py
>>> df
               Country                                   Languages Spoken
0          Afghanistan  Dari Persian, Pashtu (both official), other Tu...
1              Algeria         Arabic (official), French, Berber dialects
2              Andorra  Catalán (official), French, Castilian, Portuguese
3               Angola  Portuguese (official), Bantu and other African...
4  Antigua and Barbuda                 English (official), local dialects
5            Australia            English 79%, native and other languages
>>>
>>> >>> df['English speaking'] = df['Languages Spoken'].str.contains('English')
>>> df
               Country                                   Languages Spoken  English speaking
0          Afghanistan  Dari Persian, Pashtu (both official), other Tu...             False
1              Algeria         Arabic (official), French, Berber dialects             False
2              Andorra  Catalán (official), French, Castilian, Portuguese             False
3               Angola  Portuguese (official), Bantu and other African...             False
4  Antigua and Barbuda                 English (official), local dialects              True
5            Australia            English 79%, native and other languages              True
```